# Drools matches with negative lookahead

Tags: regex, drools

I want one of my conditions to be that an asserted string is not in a list of strings.

I'm using a decision table and in my condition cell I have

```
firstName matches("?!($param)")
```

and in the param cell I have

```
Billy|Joe|Bob
```

For some reason when I have a name like Sally it doesn't match that rule. If I remove "Billy|Joe|Bob" from the param cell it matches.

I should probably mention that I'm using drools 3.0.6 I saw mention of a not matches that was added in drools 4 but for reasons I won't get into I can't upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've found is to split this into multiple conditions. I wish I could place these all in one condition but to do that I'm pretty sure I'd need to go up to at least drools 4.

```
| firstName!="$param" | firstName!="$param" | firstName!="$param" |
|Billy                |Joe                  |Bob                  |
```

Note: The use of pipes in the original question was to be treated as an "or" whereas here I'm using pipes to denote cells in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Negative look ahead is something completely different than negating an expression, that I think is what you are looking for.

I don't remember much of Drools 3, but you probably will have to use an eval expression to negate that. So your decision table cell would look like

```
eval( ! getFirstName().matches("($param)") )
```

Basically you are calling a pure java expression instead of using the provided matches operator.

Comment: I don't think eval is allowed in decision tables in drools 3. It says unexpected token on eval.

Comment: Decision tables are just text templates to generate rules, so they do accept evals, just a matter of finding the right syntax. Take a look at the generated rule and see what is wrong... it might help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You have the leading bracket out of place.

The syntax for a negative look ahead is:

```
(?!$param)
```

However, this change alone isn't enough. You need to anchor the regex:

```
^(?!.*$param)
```

This regex says "match any input that *doesn't* contain `$param`".

So using your example, `^(?!.*Billy|Joe|Bob)` would match any input that doesn't contain `Bill`, `Joe` or `Bob`

Comment: I tried both of those and they didn't work. I believe your regex is correct but I have a hunch that drools 3.0 doesn't support the full regex grammar.